# Passing list of values to Cucumber scenario outline

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have a scenario to validate 100 employee names, The QueryString will return them in xml format.All I want to do is to validate all the employee names in an Assertion statement like given below. Instead of adding each name in the Scenario Outline Example, Is it possible to send a list of 100 employee names as input so that I can Iterate through them in java and could easily validate in Assertion condition. Please advice.

```
Scenario Outline: When the User queries for employee information, the correct records are returned
    Given the webservice is running
    When the User queries for employee information "<QueryString>"
    Then the User receives correct data "<Name>"

Examples:
|QueryString|Name|
|Some localhost url|Peter|
|Some localhost url|Sam|
.
.

@Then("^the User receives correct data\"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void the_user_receives_correct_data(String arg1) throws Throwable {
        queryResultPage = selenium.getPageSource();
        assertTrue(queryResultPage.contains(arg1));
    }
```

Comment: You can have the names in a text file, read from the text file and generate a list. Use the list in your step defs. In this case, your feature file wont have any table with the list of names.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It seems to be work out for my scenario. I have created list of names and tried placing my file like below,        |Some localhost url|@src/test/resources/InputFile.txt|                Cucumber consider this as a text rather than a file.

Answer (score 0):

so i will answere here to LINGS comment
What you can do, is use these filenames in your step definition to load the files in your code. Cucumber doesnt support direct file loading as far as i know.
i use something like this to locate full ressource pathes for my relative path file names:

```
public static String getAbsoluteResourcePath(String resourcePath) {

    if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS) {
      return Utils.class.getResource(resourcePath).getPath().substring(1).replace("/", File.separator);
    } else {
      return Utils.class.getResource(resourcePath).getPath().replace("/", File.separator);
    }
}
```

The resourcePath should then be your relative file path

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is external test data support, which is supported with [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf). You can use any [inbuilt data provider](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html) with [interceptor](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html#data-provider-intercepter) to modify data set or [custom data provider](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd2.html#data-driven-scenario).

If you are using cucumber version 5+ you can use [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#qaf-cucumber) that will give you all qaf features with cucumber. For [lower version](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html#for-existing-cucumber-implementation) you can run your existing feature files with QAF runner.